SKSpriteNode will have some wrong change when the SKCameraNode Scale to High level
I am making a game like ColorByNumber, i ran into a tricky problem during development.
There are many SKSpriteNode in the GameScene, many blocks have many spacing.
When the SKCameraNode scale to larger view, the spacing of blocks will have something strange. ( Some hide , Some show, very ugly.
I want to know how to hide all the spacing when the SkCameraNode in larger view status. And make the GameScene more nice.


there is a json data, i use json data to render pixel picture
func computePosition(row: Int, column: Int) -> (x: Int, y: Int) {
    return (
        x: (column * 103) - (drawSize * 60) + 60,
        y: (row * 103) - (drawSize * 60) + 60
    )
}

func addPieces() {
    for row in 0...(NumRows - 1) {
        for column in 0...(NumColumns - 1) {
            let position = computePosition(row, column)

            let node = SKSpriteNode()

            node.position = position

            addChild(node)
        }
    }
}



your sample code doesn't run. node.position expects a CGPoint yet computePosition returns an int tuple. regardless, you should investigate the "moiré effect" -- it happens when one frequency is resampled at a different frequency. it's a very common phenomenon when resizing things with regular patterns like dots, grids, or stripes.

thank you very much. I am try use CGPoint for position, but they are still anomalies.I think i need to investigate the "moiré effect", this is very valuable.
